# Display JS scripts block (for example Ad words script) within Switch block / C#

Tags: c#, controls

I try to write Control (.ascx) to manage the banners at my internal pages.

I do it by switch case which for every ID match the right banner. The question - how can I put the Adwords JS script within the `switch break;`?

It should be something like:

```
switch(_bannerId) 
{ 
     case "banner1": 
     {
           <script type= >
              Google adsense code
           </script>
     }
     case "banner2": 
     {
           <script type= >
              Google adsense code
           </script>
     }

     break;  
}
```

Is it possible? How to do it?

***EDIT***

It's not working with `Response.Write()`

I tried search for, "How to call Javascript from code behind" but I couldn't find a suitable post.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply mix c# code and html, you need to treat the html code as strings and add them to page output.

Add this your .ascx file:

```
<Asp:Literal runat="server" ID="AdwordsScript"></Asp:Literal>
```

and then to your ascx.cs file:

```
switch(_bannerId) 
{ 
     case "banner1": 
     {
           AdwordsScript.Text= @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
              //Google adsense code 1
           </script>";
     }
     break;  
     case "banner2": 
     {
           AdwordsScript.Text= @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
              //Google adsense code 2
           </script>";
     }
     break;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Response.Write()` will corrupt the output markup, i.e. it will write content before `Render()` is called and thus put the script outside the document's markup. Add a `Literal` to the page and set the `Text` property of the `Literal` equal to the script.

[Better still, just use `RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx). It's intended for scenarios like this and gives you more control over when the script executes. If you are using a `ScriptManager` on the page, there is a [similar method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx).

Alternatively, to avoid large script strings in your code behind, you can declare all your script in `Placeholders` in the markup and show/hide them based on your switch statement.

### C#

```
switch(_bannerId){
  case "banner1":
      this.plhScript1.Visible = true;
      break;
  case "banner2":
      this.plhScript2.Visible = true;
      break;
  default:
      throw new InvalidOperationException( "Unknown banner type" );
}
```

### User Control

```
<asp:Placeholder runat="server" id="plhScript1" visible="false">
    <script>
    // script goes here


    </script>
</asp:Placeholder>

<asp:Placeholder runat="server" id="plhScript2" visible="false">
    <script>
    // script goes here


    </script>
</asp:Placeholder>
```